# Can't pick StaticMeshActor from scene when I create variable of that type in blueprint, if the actor is from sub-level in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I have made an blueprint and inside of it, variable of type StaticMeshActor (object reference):
[image]

When I create instance of this blueprint in scene, I get the drop-down for my “Test” variable with StaticMeshActor actors in scene (that’s correct).
But once I click on any of them (that are from sub-levels), field resets to “None” again. Same goes for picker icon from scene.
[image]

Is it bug, or am I doing something wrong? Is it even possible to select actor from sub-level?

Comment: It is not possible for an actor to make a reference to an actor from a different level, unless the reference is made at runtime.